# Compare a vector with a scalar (e.g. doubles) using Boost library C++

Tags: c++, boost, vector, comparison

I am looking for a smart way to compare a vector of elements with a scalar value of the same type, and generate the indexes of the elements that satisfy such a comparison. My current solution is:

```
boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double> myVec(3);
myVec(0) = 1.5;
myVec(1) = 2.1;
myvec(2) = 9.2;

double valToCompare = 3.5;

std::vector<int> idx;

for(int i=0 ; i<myVec.size() ; i++)
{
    if(myVec(i)<=valToCompare)
         idx.push_back(i);
}
```

Is there a way to do it more effectively?

Thanks

Comment: Is the vector sorted?  Some techniques may required a sorted vector for best efficiency.  Can the vector be modified (sorted)?

Comment: How large is the data set?  For small data sets, a linear search is usually faster or equally fast as other techniques.

Comment: The vector is not sorted. Shall I sort it first? The vector can be big, let's say > 10000 elements.

Comment: Profile & measure.  Sorting may use up all the time gained by an algorithm that requires sorted values.  See `std::lower_bound`, `std::upper_bound`, `std::binary_search`, Fibonacci Search.  You may want to use a different data structure such as `std::set`.

Comment: Cool! I will look into that! Many thanks.

Comment: "The vector is not sorted. Shall I sort it first?" -- How may times are you going to search that same vector? Considering the search you implemented is linear (and very simple), sorting is bound to be more complex, so if you only search once, you don't gain anything. -- You may want to reserve a reasonable space in the `idx` vector. Depending on the number of matches, the reallocations it will do while growing will probably cause most overhead in your algorithm.

Comment: I am searching that same vector only once. Better I don't do anything else then. For the allocation of `idx`, it would then be better to allocate memory for the worst case scenario, and then resize it in case I use less. Did I understand correctly? If I were to search multiple times, what would it be an efficient solution?